# Keeping a powershell runspace alive in C# WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, powershell, runspace

I'm planning on building an `Active Directory/Exchange` admin console using `C#` talking `powershell` to `DC` and Exchange servers.

I want to on application launch establish `powershell` connections to these servers and then keep them alive so I can keep running queries or scripts or whatever because it takes a couple of seconds to establish the remote connection and it just won't work to have that kind of delay on everything you do.

I'm currently just testing a local `powershell` runspace but every time I send a command to it it closes and I can't reuse it after the initial command.

How can I prevent the `runspace` from closing so I can use it over and over again?

edit: code
Very basic, just creating a runspace, planning on being able to include modules later on when I've got the basic functionality down. The idea was to create a runspace and when calling the function that executes powershell code assign that runspace to another variable so I could reuse it but I'm probably stupid. Currently I just have a dummy "Get-Process" that's sent when clicking a button and a textbox that displays the output.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Runspace powerShellRunspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
    public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        powerShellRunspace.Open();
        string[] modules;
        scriptOutput.Text = "test";
        modules = new string[5];
        modules[0] = "john";



        //string result = powerShellRun("Get-Process");
        //powerShellInitialize(modules);

    }

    public static void powerShellInitialize(string[] modules)
    {
        Runspace powerShellRunspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
        powerShellRunspace.Open();

    }

    public string powerShellRun(string commands, Runspace powerShellRunspace)
    {

        Runspace powerShellRunspace2 = powerShellRunspace;
        Pipeline powerShellPipeline = powerShellRunspace2.CreatePipeline();
        powerShellPipeline.Commands.Add(commands);
        Collection<PSObject> powerShellResult = powerShellPipeline.Invoke();
        //string result="temp";
        //return result;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (PSObject obj in powerShellResult)
        {
            stringBuilder.AppendLine(obj.ToString());
        }

        return stringBuilder.ToString();

    }
}
```

Comment: What does your current code look like?

Answer (score 1):

This question was already answered on [Keeping Powershell runspace open in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10702375/keeping-powershell-runspace-open-in-net?rq=1)

In summary, you can keep your Runspace Open, but for each independent query, you need to create a new Powershell instance.

Example:

```
Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(initial);
runspace.Open();

//First Query
var firstQuery = PowerShell.Create();
firstQuery.Runspace = runspace;
firstQuery.AddScript("Write-Host 'hello'")

//Second Query
var secondQuery = PowerShell.Create();
secondQuery.Runspace = runspace;
secondQuery.AddScript("Write-Host 'world'")
```